# Taking a TIF from a URL and moving it into Azure blob storage in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am calling an API which returns a path to GET a TIF image, with authentication included.

The path works, both in Postman and in my browser.\

I'd like to upload it to Azure blob storage.

Image sizes are a few K.

I'm generating a GUID, a7a67740-b809-48e0-a154-686c54c649d6 in this case, and uploading to a container with a legal name, using a connection to Azure blob storage which worked fine in other classes in this project.

Unfortunately, when I try to upload the image with this code:

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference($"{blobName}.tif");
await blockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(tif.ToString());
```

it's throwing me this error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFileName(String path)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.BeginUploadFromFile(String path, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlockBlob.cs:line 963
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.BeginUploadFromFile(String path, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlockBlob.cs:line 938
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions.TaskFromVoidApm[T1](Func`4 beginMethod, Action`1 endMethod, T1 arg1, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Util\AsyncExtensions.cs:line 174
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(String path, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlockBlob.cs:line 1065
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(String path) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlockBlob.cs:line 1053
   at DbMgr.AstroDigital.<GetTasksAsync>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\BaruchKogan\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\DbMgr\DbMgr\AstroDigital.cs:line 147
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`blockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync` requires you to specify a path to file on the local computer. Because you're specifying a URL there, you're getting this error.

From your question, it seems that the URL you're getting is publicly accessible i.e. you can take the URL and copy it in browser's address bar and you will see the image. If that is the case, then you should use `CopyBlob` method to create the blob using this URL.

```
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference($"{blobName}.tif");
        await blockBlob.StartCopyAsync(tif);//Assuming "tif" is an object of type System.Uri
```

What Azure Storage service will do is read the contents of this image from the URI and create a block blob with that.

Comment: Thank you. It's working. 

Once I've uploaded the image to blobstorage, will it appear if someone puts the full blob URL into their browser? What do I need to do to make that happen?

Comment: If you need to make this blob publicly available so that if someone puts the blob URL in the browser it gets displayed/downloaded, you would need to  change the blob container's ACL as either `Blob` or `Container`. If the blob container's ACL is private, user will get `Resource Not Found (404)` error. HTH.